# SCCM Subcriptions Account Lock-Up

Tags: sccm

I am having an issue I'm hoping someone can shed some light on.

Currently, there is a subscription running on a per-machine basis that runs the report

> Software registered in Add Remove Programs on a specific computer".

The subscription seems to work fine, however, the AD server complains about a bad password attempt, and eventually locks the network account up.  It seems odd that the report can run with bad credentials (which I've verified isn't the case), and populate the correct csv file.

The Event Viewer on the server states there are Audit Failures via Event ID: 4625, but again I am able  populate the data correctly...

Does anyone have any possible suggestions to troubleshooting this issue?